# Flutter SliverApp Bar back button not displaying at the top right

Tags: flutter

I want to display the close button using SliverAppBar at top right,now, the back button appears almost in the middle and not top right. I am using the pop up widget SlideUpPageTransitionAnimation, so it seems there is this weird spacing at the top when trying to apply padding, the button disappears when moving it to the top.
Please check my code and please assist:
This is from widget 1

```
class LiveStreamingModalVideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
................
   SliverAppBar(
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                topRight: Radius.circular(8),
              )),
              pinned: true,
              floating: false,
              expandedHeight: 370,
              collapsedHeight: kToolbarHeight,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              backgroundColor: SuperSportColorScheme.white,
              surfaceTintColor: const Color(0xFF6CAEDF),
              elevation: 0,
              forceElevated: true,
              centerTitle: true,
              flexibleSpace: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(8),
                ),
                child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: _playerSummaryInfo(),
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                _closePlayerStatusPage(team: widget.channels),
              ],
            ),

  Widget _closePlayerStatusPage({required LiveVideo? team}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: 15,
      ),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          close_white_button,
          height: 24,
          width: 24,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          if (mounted) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Where I am calling it in another widget 2:

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
        SlideUpPageTransitionAnimation(
          page: SlinkyCardWidget(
            child: LiveStreamingModalVideoWidget(channels: liveVideo),
          ),
        ),
      );
```